# How to use 2 Ethernet ports on the same computer to connect 2 different routers

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, vpn, ethernet

I have a desktop with 2 Gigabit LAN ports, I need to connect to the main router in the house so I can run my VPN and access my data offsite.  However, I also need to be able to use the router in my room for things like Xbox and such.  How would I go about bridging these connections so that I can use both routers and give internet access to them both?

Comment: Can you expand how your devices and router setup?  What is connected to what router?  What is connected to your computer?

Comment: sure, my computer is currently connected to my second router as a user, this router goes behind my first router (needed by verizon, ghh), the verizon router is only used to get internet currently, as a run a cable right out of it into my room, however, my vpn will not work when it is on my second router, because it is behind the first and I do not know which ports to forward in order to make the router in my room the primary, they stuff in my room is all the dev stuff im working on, so I kind of need it running and on the internet

Comment: So, you have a main router somewhere in your house.  The router in your room is connected to the first router by... (wire or wireless?)  I am assuming that your computer is plugged into that router.  Correct?

Comment: connected by wire, yes

Comment: if I was truly devouted, I could always run a second cable, its just a pain that I dont feel like dealing with because its like a 100 ft run

Comment: It's a hundred foot run from your Xbox to your router in your bedroom?  Is the computer, xbox, and second router all the in the same room?  What type of router is it?